# when does a partial differential equation have unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The differential equation $ xu_x + yu_y = 2u$ satisfying the initial conditions $y = xg(x), u=f(x)$ with

1. $f(x) = 2x, g(x) = 1$, has no solution
2. $f(x) = 2x^2, g(x) =1$, has infinite number of solutions
3. $f(x) = x^3, g(x) = x$, has a unique solution
4. $f(x) = x^4, g(x) = x$, has a unique solution

I don't know when a partial differential equation has unique solution, infinite solutions or no solution. can I solve this by Cauchy's method of characteristics? I have no idea. please help.

Comment: I can't find any initial conditions. All I can see is an equation relating the independent variables $y=xg(x)$ such that they're not independent any more and an equation stating that the prospective solution $u$ is a function of $x$ only?